# How can I determine the current selected tab?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost that has two tabs. Each tab has its own intent:

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ARActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("trending").setIndicator("Trending",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WatchlistActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("watchlist").setIndicator("Watchlist",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

**How can I determine which tab is selected when I am in ARActivity or when I am in WatchlistActivity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use tabHost.getCurrentTab() onResume() of both the activity to detect which tab you have selected.